# How do I make 'bit' array instead of 'int' array?

Tags: c++, arrays, int, bit

Conventionally, in C++, upon creating an array, I declare it as an int.
However, since I am only dealing with binary numbers (1 and 0 only), I am thinking that is that possible for me to covert the 4 bytes 'int' to 1 bit.

For example

```
int array1[] = {1,0,0,0,0,1,0}; // -----had total of 32 bytes
```

Since it's only binary, the memory efficiency is just 1/32 as each int 1's will store as `000000000000000000000000000001` (4 bytes).

So my question is how can I convert all this into bit so that the 32 bytes can be 'compressed' into 1 byte (instead of 8 int of 32 bytes, I want a 8 bits data) ?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset - this should do the trick

Comment: You can use `std::vector<bool>`

Comment: Is the length of your array compile-time constant or only known at run time?

Comment: _"had total of 32 bytes"_ Can you elaborate on your measuring technique? That just sounds odd.

Comment: Why not using an array of boolean in c++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [std::bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/). I think this is what you want.

I don't know if you are a competitive programmer but sometimes in competitive programming it is required to have 10^9 flags. Then `bitset` or in sieve's prime determination this is extremely helpful.

```
#include<bitset>
...
...
bitset<10000000> bs;

..
bs[1]=1;
bs[i]=0;
..etc
```

Comment: Hi,how do i use bitset for an array?(allocating into a array)

Comment: last question, what about allocating it into multi dimensional array?

Comment: @CHONG.: I have used once using 'BOOST' library..`dynamic_bitset`

Comment: @CHONG Before accepting prematurely take a look at my answer. I think `std::vector<bool>` is more appropriate for what you want (including having multiple dimensions).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ ...i do know that bool works, just that bitset is more appropriate to make it 1 bit(for my question) , bool is not one byte as i tested.

Answer (score 4):

> Conventionally, in C++, upon creating an array, I declare it as an int.

There's no such common convention.

> However, since I am only dealing with binary numbers (1 and 0 only), I am thinking that is that possible for me to covert the 4 bytes 'int' to 1 bit.

Naturally one might think that this should result in declaring something like

```
bool array1[]{true,false,false,false,false,true,false};
```

Though the above implementation just reduces the space used for a single bit to `unsigned char`, which is the smallest memory unit that can be addressed in c++.

---

Fortunately c++ provides a specialization of [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) that actually space optimizes your bit array as you want to.

Comment: oh dear god `std::vector<bool>`, just no, keep it away from us

Comment: @Puppy For the case asked for it's exactly what the OP wants. I didn't say that `std::vector<bool>` is a real good implementation to tackle the general problem.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  std::vector<bool>  size is one byte, i need it to be one bit, as i am doing millions time of iterations, i think that fetching 1 bit compare to one bytes millions time should improve some of its performance, just trying out.

Comment: @CHONG _"`std::vector<bool>` size is one byte"_ No, it's size isn't one byte. You misunderstood, `std::vector<bool>` is space optimized, and allocates as many bytes needed to fit your bits in.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ i agree on that, sorry for the 'one byte'.
as far as i tested, for a e.g length of 32  , it gives 16 bytes.

Comment: @CHONG _"as far as i tested, for a e.g length of 32"_ How did you test it?`sizeof(std::vector<bool>)` just fools you here. It's not the size of the actual data kept in the vector.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ, erm...ok...i am not sure about it ...but how should i test it, 
ps: my whole approach was using bool already, just that i need it to be faster.

Comment: @CHONG Well, `std::bitset` forces you to declare the maximum size of bits in advance at compile time, while `std::vector<bool>` doesn't. As others mentioned there's also `boost::dynamic_bitset` which might be a better implementation. If you can actually tell how many bits need to be stored as maximum, `std::bitset` might give you better performance. BTW don't try to implement Huffman Compression or such things based on either of the proposals.